# Develop a Form Designer Application

Tags: .net, ide, custom-controls

I have been tasked to create a form designer application in Windows Forms.  The application will be used to layout "controls" on a page.  The controls would most likely be images that can be resized and repositioned within the form.  The result of the designer would be a file with the relative positions of the images or "controls" on the form.

I can figure out how to make the file representing the positions, but I have know idea how to make the IDE like form designer.  Does anyone have any suggestions for existing controls that would allow for the adding and manipulating of images on the screen or is this going to have to be something that is homegrown?

Comment: What language/platform will you be working with?

Comment: "Windows Forms" would suggest to me .Net to me, so C#/vb.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) has a fully functioning forms designer built in, and the code base is open-source.

Comment: +1 SharpDevelop is a great project but there a couple of caveats: 1) isolating a subset of the technology for use elsewhere might be challenging due to some interdependencies. i've been bitten by this. 2) the structure of the code is good but very advanced. An entry-level developer might run him/herself in circles in it.

Answer (score 0):

There are [many articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/magazine/cc159300.aspx) about windows forms designer hosting published by MSDN magazine. Just search "designer" in the article list.